# How obtain random UID using HCE?

Tags: android, random, nfc, uniqueidentifier, hce

I have an Android app that sends a value over NFC using host card emulation.
I know the UID is random but it is possible to know the UID when I approach the device to reader NFC?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need this - does the value you send depend on the randomly generated UID somehow?

Anyway, there's currently no official API to retrieve the (random) UID during a HCE session; NFC controllers typically don't expose the UID they generate to the OS.